# File path issue with: / -> \

Tags: java, string, file, path

```
            // Dividend Limit check or increase the Dividend
        if (dival == 10) {
            writer.println("Divident has reached it Limit !");
            i++;
            // update the file name
            String upath = "channel_" + i;
            System.out.println(path);
            // find channel_1 and replace with the updated path
            if (path.contains("channel_1")) {
                path = "D:/File Compression/Data/low_freq/low_freq/house_1/"
                        + upath + ".dat";
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid File Choosen");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            dival = 10;

        } else {
            dival = dival + 10;
            writer.println("Dividen:" + dival);
        }
```

these lines are in a recursive method. first time it gives right path:

```
D:/File Compression/Data/low_freq/low_freq/house_1/channel_2.dat
```

But on the second call it flips the forward slash to back slash:

```
D:\File Compression\Data\low_freq\low_freq\house_1\channel_1.dat
```

it works fine if I do not use the condition.

```
if(path.contains("channel_"))
```

Comment: The code you have posted does not exhibit this problem. Where does 'path' come from? NB there is never any need to use a backslash in a Java file name.

Comment: @EJP path is coming from String path is static and it is in other class so i call it from class name and use that path here.
here is the code 
    `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
      "Data File", "dat");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(getParent());
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
path = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

    }
   }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**\** is called as **Escape sequence** in java which is used in various purposes .

In your case use `File.separator`

```
String path = "D:"+File.separator+"File Compression"+File.separator+"Data"+File.separator+"low_freq"+File.separator+"low_freq"+File.separator+"house_1"+File.separator;
```

Use double slash **\\** ! It's a special escape pattern. Like \n or \r.
**Escape sequence** normally used in text files in Windows, specially in notepad.

The primary Java escape sequences are listed below. They are used to represent non-graphical characters and also characters such as double quotes, single quotes, and backslashes. If you'd like to represent a double quote within a String literal, you can do so with \". If you'd like to represent a single quote within a character literal, you can do so with \'.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That is because the `File.seperator` in Windows is `\`. Every time you let your path String go through a `java.io.File` it will replace them. So to fix this, either don't use File as auxiliary tool, or replace the backslashes with forward slashes.

So, what happens is that your `path` String uses backward slashes. You retrieve that String form a `java.io.File` which will automatically uses backslashes on Windows. If the path contains "channel_1", then you overwrite the whole string using a hardcoded string with forward slashes.

Comment: Do you know the solution to this problem ?

Comment: The code does not show how or where it goes through a java.io.File, thogh.

Comment: I know. But there is as far as I know no other explanation for this behavior, so I guess there is missing a part of the code.

Comment: i am using java.io.file

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux actually i am doing this because i have files in different folders so i get the path and just replace the "channel_1" with "channel_"+i and if i hardcode it i will not be able to achieve my objective

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers. You should not use `/` or `\` hard coded in your application. Because this will harm the portability of your application. rather use,

```
File.separator
```

[File#separator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/File.java#File.0separator) gives you, the separator depending in your system.