# MultipartFile - getOriginalFilename removes characters before backslash

Tags: java, groovy

If the filename contains **one** or **many** backslashes all characters before the backslashes are removed by the `getOriginalFilename()` function.

Let say the file name is `"my_file_\\\\\\\\\_test.mp3"`

**I have this code:**

```
def file = request.getFile("file"); //org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile
```

when debugging `file.fileItem.fileName` is correct it shows `"my_file_\\\\\\\\\_test.mp3"`

But when I call `file.getOriginalFilename();`

```
def newFile = file.getOriginalFilename();

System.out.print(newFile);// `"_test.mp3"`
```

All the characters before the backslash are removed. Why is this happening ? Should I use `file.fileItem.fileName` instead ?

Comment: Maybe because of the special meaning of backslash? [Escape Sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

Comment: See also here: [File path issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673745/file-path-issue-with)

Comment: Btw, who names files like this? That should not be allowed(like in windows) o.O

Comment: @asdf never trust the user is a basic